# Graph Matrix project (non-static in static)

Tags: java, graph, matrix

I have an assignment to code a graph matrix that takes numbers labels them and spits out the connections. Right now have the basic problem of this non-static/static stuff. I don't understand the problem even though I thought I understood the difference between a class and an instance of that class. When i run this there is a problem at first for loop. Won't pause for input of the labels. I appreciate any help and/or criticisms.

```
public class GraphMatrix {

class Matrix {

    private int matrix[][];
    private int size;
    private String labels[];

    private void createMatrix() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many points will be represented in this graph?");
        size = in.nextInt();
        matrix = new int[size][size];
        labels = new String[size];
        System.out.println("Please label each point.");
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter label for point #" + (i));
            String key = in.nextLine();
            labels[i] = key;
        }
        System.out.println("Please define edges between points or enter -1 when finished:");
        int finish = 1;
        while (finish == 1) {
            int jkey = 0;
            int kkey = 0;
            int count = 0;
            boolean pass = false;
            System.out.println("Point labeled:");
            String j = in.nextLine();
            while (pass = false) {
                if (labels[count].equals(j)) {
                    jkey = count;
                    count = 0;
                    pass = true;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("to point labeled:");
            String k = in.nextLine();
            while (pass = true) {
                if (labels[count].equals(j)) {
                    kkey = count;
                    pass = false;
                }
            }
            matrix[jkey][kkey] = 1;
            System.out.println("Finished enter -1, to define more connections enter 1");
            finish = in.nextInt();
        }

    }

    private void listEdges() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
                    System.out.println("There is an edge between" + labels[i] + " and" + labels[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matrix neo = new Matrix();
    neo.createMatrix();
    neo.listEdges();
}
```

}

Comment: If your compiler is giving you any errors, please post them here and indicate to us which line(s) are causing them.

Comment: After taking a curosory look at your code, I don't see any issues with respect to static vs non-static issues.  As Hovercraft said, please post your errors.

Comment: I agree with @SteveP. It looks like your title has absolutely nothing to do with the code you're displaying. Please clarify.

Comment: Or at least `pass == false`.  There's a similar problem a few lines later with `pass = true`.  Should be simply `while(pass)` or `while(pass == true)`.

Comment: There is no problems compiling. My problem is in the first for loop where it doesnt wait for input so i get:

Enter label for point #1
Enter label for point #2

Doesnt wait for input for label #1

Answer (score 2):

You need to make change in **main** method as follows to remove  compiler error.

From

```
 Matrix neo = new Matrix();
```

to

```
  GraphMatrix graphMatrix = new GraphMatrix();
    Matrix neo = graphMatrix.new Matrix();
```

**Note:** To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this syntax:

```
 OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see one significant problem in your code.

This `while (pass = false) {` should be `while (!pass) {`

and `while (pass = true) {` should be `while (pass) {`

Also: Why are you nesting the Matrix class inside of the GraphMatrix class? That doesn't make sense to me. If I were you, I wouldn't do this unless it is an explicit requirement of your assignment.

Comment: Probably worth noting he has the same problem a few lines later with `while(pass = true)`.  `while(pass == true)` or simple `while(pass)`, both acceptable, but single `=` is problematic in both `while`.